# Android aar file with dependencies

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, transitive-dependency

Currently I need to build an Android library .aar file. In the library have network request so that I have to add Retrofit as library's dependencies.
My library build.gradle file look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
}
```

But when using aar file by

```
compile(name:'sdk-release', ext:'aar'){transitive=true}
```

It's throw exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

After research, I figured out that the Problem is "transitive dependencies".

Do we have any solution to fix this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Kindly try to add your library( i.e your .aar file) in build.gradle like this

 **compile project(':your_library_name')**

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ?